# Blender exporter (v70) to json three.js skinning animations

Tags: animation, three.js, skinning, blender-2.61, exporter

It took me a few weeks to master the Blender to json skinning export process, but the final result was working great prior three.js exporter v70.

I had to rebuild my dev machine and I installed Blender three.js exporter v70.

Today, I am doing a simple update to a blender file with skinning animations that was working fine prior the update and I am not able to get multiple animations to export as before.

I  have tested Blender exporter with a simple object and animations and I get the same results.

Exporter output:

```js
{
    "metadata": {
        "bones": 3,
        "faces": 10,
        "vertices": 12,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "normals": 12,
        "type": "Geometry",
        "version": 3
    },
    "name": "CubeGeometry.3",
    "bones": [{
        "pos": [0.0,0.0,-0.0],
        "name": "center",
        "rotq": [0,0,0,1],
        "parent": -1
    },{
        "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
        "name": "right",
        "rotq": [0,0,0,1],
        "parent": 0
    },{
        "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
        "name": "left",
        "rotq": [0,0,0,1],
        "parent": 0
    }],
    "animation": {
        "name": "right",
        "length": 4.125,
        "hierarchy": [{
            "keys": [{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,0.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0],
                "time": 0.0
            },{
                "pos": [0.0,0.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0],
                "time": 2.0416666666666665
            },{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,0.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0],
                "time": 4.125
            }],
            "parent": -1
        },{
            "keys": [{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0],
                "time": 0.0
            },{
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,0.33748486638069153,0.9413309693336487],
                "time": 2.0416666666666665
            },{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [0.0,0.0,-0.0,1.0],
                "time": 4.125
            }],
            "parent": 0
        },{
            "keys": [{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [-6.0461669172803476e-15,1.149220128782158e-11,0.00026304941275157034,0.9999613761901855],
                "time": 0.0
            },{
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [-6.0461669172803476e-15,1.149220128782158e-11,0.00026304941275157034,0.9999613761901855],
                "time": 2.0416666666666665
            },{
                "scl": [1,1,1],
                "pos": [0.0,1.0,-0.0],
                "rot": [-6.0461669172803476e-15,1.149220128782158e-11,0.00026304941275157034,0.9999613761901855],
                "time": 4.125
            }],
            "parent": 1
        }],
        "fps": 24
    },
    "faces": [33,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,33,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,33,0,4,5,1,0,4,7,1,33,1,5,6,2,1,7,6,2,33,6,7,11,10,6,5,8,9,33,4,0,3,7,4,0,3,5,33,8,10,11,9,10,9,8,11,33,7,3,9,11,5,3,11,8,33,2,6,10,8,2,6,9,10,33,3,2,8,9,3,2,10,11],
    "vertices": [1.8709198236465454,-0.05566583573818207,-0.9999999403953552,1.8709198236465454,-0.055665746331214905,0.9999999403953552,-0.12908029556274414,-0.055665746331214905,0.9999998211860657,-0.12907981872558594,-0.05566583573818207,-1.0000003576278687,1.8709203004837036,1.9443342685699463,-0.9999995231628418,1.8709192276000977,1.9443342685699463,1.0000004768371582,-0.12908053398132324,1.9443342685699463,0.9999995827674866,-0.12908011674880981,1.9443342685699463,-1.0000001192092896,-1.9279574155807495,-0.055665984749794006,0.9999994039535522,-1.9279569387435913,-0.05566607415676117,-1.0000007152557373,-1.9279578924179077,1.9443340301513672,0.9999991655349731,-1.9279574155807495,1.9443340301513672,-1.0000004768371582],
    "influencesPerVertex": 2,
    "skinWeights": [1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0,1.0,0],
    "normals": [0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,0.0,-0.7070833444595337,0.7070833444595337,0.0,-0.7070833444595337,-0.7070833444595337,0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.0,0.7070833444595337,-0.7070833444595337,0.0,0.7070833444595337,0.7070833444595337,0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035,-0.5773491859436035],
    "skinIndices": [2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
}
```

Any idea what should I be doing to get multiple skinning animations working again?

Cordially,
j3zusla

Comment: I went back to the exporter v69 and all is working again. I believe this is a version issue. The multiple animation function was a new feature added not too long ago to the exporter. It was certainly omitted in v70.

Answer (score 1):

Until r71 is released it is advised to use the [dev](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev) version. Multiple animations have been restored plus numerous optimizations, features, and bug fixes have been addressed (specifically to animation exports).

Comment: I have downloaded and installed blender-exporter dev snapshot 27/02/2015. Unfortunatly, the export function keeps giving the error "Armature is not a valid mesh object" when exporting skinning animations. I've tried to permute the options but the outcome is the same.

Comment: Because you had the armature selected. In the current state of the exporter you need to explicitly select the mesh. I am aware that the old exporter this wasn't a requirement but it isn't a high priority item until we get all bugs and kinks worked out.

Comment: I understand... Great, I confirm animation

Comment: Great, I confirm the dev export version is fully working from the skinning animations point of view. Thank you for your help on that matter. Plus I wanted to let the Three.js team and community know that what you are doing is huge. Most people are not aware of how much it takes to satisfy everyone and still get the ball rolling. You can be proud on all aspects of your work on this framework. From my side, I am not yet ready to participate, but one day I will give you as much (or more) as you have provided! Love j3zusla